# Possible to create pages within subdomain using CNAME?

Tags: redirect, ftp, subdomain, cname, mls

janedoe.com is a normal website, built in php and html with one exception. Because the website is for a realtor, she needed to have the ability to allow her clients to search the MLS for properties (called IDX).

In order to get the IDX Search to actually be on janedoe.com, we had to use a subdomain, properties.janedoe.com, and then create a CNAME, which points to their IDX search.

My problem is: 
properties.janedoe.com and others return a 404 because the IDX search doesn't use those pages.

Can I somehow, even though there is a CNAME record, create pages under the subdomain?

--If not is there some way, whether through .htaccess or otherwise, that I can do something like a 301 redirect so that if for some reason someone went to http://properties.janedoe.com/, they wouldn't be given this:
I'd also like to be able to install my sitemap generator to the subdomain as well if there's a way to access FTP despite the CNAME.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem - or rather, what the problem has to do with the thing you're asking, creating pages on a subdomain. Can you clarify? Where is this IDX search running, on what server?

Comment: Certainly it is possible to use any hostname / subdomain as base for any "website" with "pages". It is irrelevant of the name resolution is done via an A, an AAA or a CNAME record. I have the impression your _real_ question is if that provider allows to you to use your account that way. For that I suggest you ask your provider - he should know and be able to give a clear answer. Makes more sense than use here _guessing_.

Comment: The provider will allow me to use my account that way. I am just not familiar with DNS configuration. So, keeping in mind that there is a CNAME in place, what would I need to do in order to put my own pages in that same subdomain?

Comment: What is that subdomain currently running, and on what server? What kind of a product is IDX search - do you have it installed somewhere?

Comment: The subdomain is currently running nothing, per-say. It is simply a CNAME to the IDX. IDX is a tool for users to search for homes that are listed in MLS from a personal website. 

Linux CentOS as far as hosting (hostgator)